# How can I steal a bag of holding, or magically swap one with another?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, teleportation

My rogue friend has stolen something from me, and I want to take it back without them knowing it (at first). The object is inside a Bag of Holding that they keep on their person at all times.

**Is there a spell to swap the empty Bag of Holding I have with the Bag of Holding they have? Or a spell to just teleport their Bag of Holding to my location?**

Help this non-dexterous character one up their friend.

I am currently a level 9 blood hunter. Stat spread is 23/16/20/14/12/15.

I have tried a direct confrontation, but that did not go my way; I have even tried to grapple the rogue, but they were too slippery so they are now on guard even more.

I would prefer this to be subtle since I don't want to make an enemy of my whole party, but I am willing to direct a few spells at the rogue during combat so they reach 0 hit points and I can just waltz over and take the bag uncontested.

Comment: Which class and level is your character?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: We can't answer this without knowing what class and level you are.

Comment: What options have you considered so far? Do you have any sort of a plan?

Comment: Do you need to  do this subtly?

Comment: What Order are you? You mention spells, so are you Profane Soul? If so, what spells do you know? Can you also provide some info on why the rogue stole this from you?